# Is there an approach to showing the difference between 2 text fields in a MVC3, Razor application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I have 2 fields with with. One is a master field and can be cloned. I display both via HTML.DisplayFor. I am trying to work out a pragmatic approach to show any changes that might be made to the master, so that the user can update the clone if required. I supposed this is a kind of "Track Changes" feature. Thought I have had include:

1) Compare Update Dates for each field as each exist in a different record. However this just shows that record has changed.

2) Compare both, and if different, indicate to user. Again just shows that the text is same or different, not what is different.

Not sure if there are any utilities/Assemblies that provide the highlighting/crossing out type "Tracking" features.

Many thanks for any help.

EDIT

I think this may be more complicated. I think I actually need to compare my new value with the original value, then show the change. So the original should be saved away in a log table, so I then have an old version and a new version. What the Clone is, is irrelevant since the user may have changed this further.

Comment: is there any reason you cant just do this with jquery?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No. If it is simpler, then fine.

Comment: IS there a tracking/comparison JQuery plugin? Is this your train of thought?

Comment: See EDIT, as it may be more complicated than I thought....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not quite sure I understand the idea behind the master/clone/hidden field stuff so I kinda improvised a bit on that part, but I think this should at least give you an idea on how you can do this.

This will basically store the original "master" value in this field:

`@Html.Hidden("hidden", "I am a hidden field");`

Note that you can perfectly set this value when you are returning a viewmodel by using

```
@Html.HiddenFor()
```

When the user tabs out of the `master` textbox, and the value is not equal to "I am a hidden field", an alert will be shown. (do note that you need to load jquery in some way, either loading it explicitly like i did below, or by using `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#master").focusout(function () {
            compareValues();
        });      

        function compareValues(){
            if ($("#master").val() !=  $("#hidden").val())
            {
                $("#hidden").val();
                alert("Original master value: " + $("#hidden").val() + " new master value: " + $("#master").val());
            }
        }

    });
</script>

@Html.Hidden("hidden", "I am a hidden field");

<input type="text"  id="master" />
<input type="text"  id="clone"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Blimey that was quick. Thanks. Will have a look

Comment: @SamJolly hi, i noticed that you accepted the answer, so i'm guessing you got it working? :)